# If statement vs if-else statement, which is faster?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, assembly, microbenchmark

I argued with a friend the other day about those two snippets. Which is faster and why ?

```
value = 5;
if (condition) {
    value = 6;
}
```

and:

```
if (condition) {
    value = 6;
} else {
    value = 5;
}
```

What if `value` is a matrix ?

Note: I know that `value = condition ? 6 : 5;` exists and I expect it to be faster, but it wasn't an option.

**Edit** (requested by staff since question is on hold at the moment):

- please answer by considering either *x86 assembly* generated by mainstream compilers (*say g++, clang++, vc, mingw*) in both optimized and non optimized versions or *MIPS assembly*.
- when assembly differ, explain why a version is faster and when (*e.g. "better because no branching and branching has following issue blahblah"*)

Comment: The optimization will kill all that out... it doesn't matter...

Comment: You could profile it, personally I doubt you'd see any difference using a modern compiler.

Comment: It is c++,  not java, compiler will manage all the stuff, both are same

Comment: However you look at it, it would be sad if doing **strictly more** actions resulted in faster execution time..

Comment: @nikeshjoshi you're probably right given the OP tagged C++11, but not all compilers would optimise.

Comment: Using `value = condition ? 6 : 5;` instead of `if/else` will most likely result in the same code being generated. Look at the assembly output if you want to know more.

Comment: the most important thing in this case is to avoid the branch, which is the most expensive thing here. ( pipe reload, discard pre-fetched instructions etc.)

Comment: @MichaelWalz: It depends on the type of `value`. With an `if`/`else`, the default constructor has to be called first, and then the assignment operator. With `?:` you can directly build in place.

Comment: The only time it makes any sense to micro-optimize for speed like this is inside a loop that will run many many times, and either the optimizer can optimize out all the branch instructions, as gcc can for this trivial example, or real-world performance will depend heavily on correct branch prediction (obligatory link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array).  If you’ll unavoidably branch inside a loop, you can help the branch predictor by generating a profile and recompiling with it.

Comment: The answer is, "it depends." It's impossible to say in isolation. If you want to know which is faster *in your specific circumstance*, you have to time it.

Comment: Doesn't this depend _entirely_ on what `value` is, and what the assignment operator does on it? If it has side effects the two snippets don't even do the same thing.

Comment: This question is too broad. It is missing a sscce, and it doesn't specify specific hardware and compiler. This means that when answering broad assumptions must be made, making any answer correct.

Comment: Personally, I would _assume_ that 1) If `condition` is `true`, the second version is faster (the first is assign-compare-assign-jump, the second is compare-assign-jump).  2) If `condition` is `false`, both are equal (one assignment, one comparison, and one jump).  3) If optimisations are enabled, it doesn't matter because they'll both be compiled to the same thing, which will be whatever the compiler considers most efficient.  After assuming, I might or might not be surprised, depending on whether the compiler uses the approach I expect it would in unoptimised code.

Comment: Answer "which is faster" questions by **running the code**. You took the time to write it; now take the time to **run it**. The one that runs faster when you run it **is the faster one**.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

**TL;DR:** In unoptimized code, `if` without `else` seems irrelevantly more efficient but with even the most basic level of optimization enabled the code is basically rewritten to `value = condition + 5`.

---

I [gave it a try](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) and generated the assembly for the following code:

```
int ifonly(bool condition, int value)
{
    value = 5;
    if (condition) {
        value = 6;
    }
    return value;
}

int ifelse(bool condition, int value)
{
    if (condition) {
        value = 6;
    } else {
        value = 5;
    }
    return value;
}
```

On gcc 6.3 with optimizations disabled (`-O0`), the relevant difference is:

```
 mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 5
 cmp     BYTE PTR [rbp-4], 0
 je      .L2
 mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 6
.L2:
 mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
```

for `ifonly`, while `ifelse` has

```
 cmp     BYTE PTR [rbp-4], 0
 je      .L5
 mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 6
 jmp     .L6
.L5:
 mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 5
.L6:
 mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
```

The latter looks slightly less efficient because it has an extra jump but both have at least two and at most three assignments so unless you really need to squeeze every last drop of performance (hint: unless you are working on a space shuttle you don't, and even then you *probably* don't) the difference won't be noticeable.

However, even with the lowest optimization level (`-O1`) both functions reduce to the same:

```
test    dil, dil
setne   al
movzx   eax, al
add     eax, 5
```

which is basically the equivalent of

```
return 5 + condition;
```

assuming `condition` is zero or one.
Higher optimization levels don't really change the output, except they manage to avoid the `movzx` by efficiently zeroing out the `EAX` register at the start.

---

**Disclaimer:** You probably shouldn't write `5 + condition` yourself (even though the standard guarantees that converting `true` to an integer type gives `1`) because your intent might not be immediately obvious to people reading your code (which may include your future self). The point of this code is to show that what the compiler produces in both cases is (practically) identical. [Ciprian Tomoiaga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202012/if-statement-vs-if-else-statement-which-is-faster/43202221?noredirect=1#comment73501865_43202221) states it quite well in the comments:

> a **human**'s job is to write code **for humans** and let the **compiler** write code for **the machine**.

Comment: I would've never though of using the addition (<- what python does to you.)

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga and unless you're writing an optimiser, you shouldn't! In almost all cases you should let the compiler do optimisations like this, especially where they severely reduce code readability. Only if performance testing shows issues with a certain bit of code should you even start to try to optimise it, and even then keep it clean and well-commented, and only perform optimisations that make a measurable difference.

Comment: This answers fails to account for the question: *what if `value` is a matrix*? Optimizers are *very* good with primitive types, but the same optimizations are not necessarily available with user-defined types.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Define "matrix". That part of the question is too unclear to answer. In any case this answer adequately describes the techniques needed to determine the results for *any* value type, an exhaustive list of all possible value types (and on all compilers on all platforms, if you want to be thorough) is neither possible nor useful. Just do the same analysis that was done here, but with a "matrix" or a "widget" or a `double` or whatever (and with your compiler on your target platform) instead.

Comment: Well done @CompuChip. In fact, this addition trick is very well found (from a theoretical view, at last). But what if we change the lines of code `value = 6` to `value = -1`? Would the compiler, under the same optimization level, do a `return 5 + (condition * -6)`?

Comment: @JasonC: I agree that the techniques are useful; my worry is that someone might imagine that this optimization is *automatic* when in fact it's fairly specialized and relies on the compiler being able to optimize away a number of unnecessary allocations/writes in the general case.

Comment: @MatthieuM. A mention that it is *"fairly specialized and relies on the compiler being able to optimize away a number of unnecessary allocations/writes in the general case"* in this answer, then, would be an excellent catch-all strategy rather than adding another example (which leaves you with the same problem, just with one more specific example). And, of course, in the bigger picture, I'm generally convinced that the people who *truly need* to learn more either *will* learn more or eventually natural selection will happen (and if neither of those happens, then it didn't matter anyways). :)

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga another reason you shouldn't is that I think the standard does not state that casting true to an int always produces 1, just a non-zero value. The assembly code doesn't assume this either actually, it depends on the `setne` instruction which is documented to set the register to 0 or 1. As I tried to stress in the answer, let the compiler do this, don't go micro-optimize on your own!

Comment: I wanted to reply to Muzer, but it wouldn't have added anything to the thread. However, I just want to restate that a **human**'s job is to write code **for humans** and let the **compiler** write code for **the machine**. I said that from a compiler developer PoV (which I'm not, but I learnt a bit about them)

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga: Python actually does let you do `condition + 5`, assuming `condition` is a boolean. Many Python users feel this shouldn't be allowed, but it is the way it is.

Comment: @CompuChip: Computers often know things that humans don't, and humans often know things that computers don't.  Given something like `if (x == 23 && x) {...} else switch(x) {...}`, moving the code from the "if" into "case 23" is apt to improve performance unless `x` happens to be 23 more than some fraction of the time.  The compiler may have a better sense than the programmer what the break-even fraction would be, but the programmer may know more than the compiler about how often `x` will be 23.

Comment: [The value `true` converted to `int` always yields 1, period.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.integral#4) Of course, if your condition is merely "truthy" and not the `bool` value `true`, then that's a completely different matter.

Comment: "unless you are working on a space shuttle you don't, and even then you _probably_ don't" -- +1, and if performance is _that_ critical, you're likely writing it in assembly anyway....

Comment: @nrocha this particular compiler (probably most others) will eventually rewrite the code to return `(-condition) | 5`, so if `condition` is 0 it gives `(-0) | 5 = 0` and if condition is 1 then `neg(1) = 11...11` so the `or` just returns 5. Note that in the answer I provided a link where you can easily try it yourself.

Comment: @CompuChip - Obviously, this question is about C/C++, but is there a different answer if you are using a language without a compiler like python or Javascript? In the case where it is interpreted, does the interpreter still make the best optimisations?

Comment: Wouldn't it also depend if condition is mostly true or false. I think that the CPU likes to predict what is the outcome of a jump before executing it.

Comment: I think there are places that this maters more than rocket science - high frequency forex trading could be one?

Answer (score 45):

The answer from [CompuChip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43202221/2805305) shows that for `int` they both are optimized to the same assembly, so it doesn't matter.

> What if value is a matrix ?

I will interpret this in a more general way, i.e. what if `value` is of a type  whose constructions and assignments are expensive (and moves are cheap).

then

```
T value = init1;
if (condition)
   value = init2;
```

is sub-optimal because in case `condition` is true, you do the unnecessary initialization to `init1` and then you do the copy assignment.

```
T value;
if (condition)
   value = init2;
else
   value = init3;
```

This is better. But still sub-optimal if default construction is expensive and if copy construction is more expensive then initialization.

You have the conditional operator solution which is good:

```
T value = condition ? init1 : init2;
```

Or, if you don't like the conditional operator, you can create a helper function like this:

```
T create(bool condition)
{
  if (condition)
     return {init1};
  else
     return {init2};
}

T value = create(condition);
```

Depending on what `init1` and `init2` are you can also consider this:

```
auto final_init = condition ? init1 : init2;
T value = final_init;
```

But again I must emphasize that this is relevant only when construction and assignments are really expensive for the given type. And even then, only by **profiling** you know for sure.

Comment: Expensive **and** not optimized out. For example, if the default constructor zeroes-out the matrix, the compiler could realize that the assignment is just about overwriting those 0s, so not zero it at all, and write directly in this memory. Of course, optimizers are finicky beasts so it's hard to predict when they kick in or not...

Comment: @MatthieuM. of course. What I meant by "expensive" is "expensive to execute (by a metric, be it either CPU clocks, resource utilization etc.) even after compiler optimizations.

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that default construction would be expensive but moves cheap.

Comment: @plugwash  Consider a class with a very large allocated array.  Default constructor allocates and initializes the array, which is costly.  The move (not copy!) constructor can just swap pointers with the source object and doesn't need to allocate or initialize the large array.

Comment: As long as the parts are simple, I would definitely prefer using the `?:` operator over introducing a new function. After all, you'll likely not just pass the condition to the function, but also some constructor arguments. Some of which may not even be used by `create()` depending on the condition.

Comment: @cmaster I've seen (and been) on both sides of the arguments of for and  agains `?:`. Ultimately I guess it's a matter of style and for every one who says you should use one you'll find another one who says you should use the other. The argument that slightly tipped the balance for me is that in debug the branch taken can be identified quicker in an `if` structure than in a `?:` operator.

Comment: @MatthieuM.  If the compiler only has a declaration of that constructor from the `class`, and the zeroing out is in a separately compiled `cpp`, it's a very unlikely optimization.

Comment: @Kaz: Well, things are blurry today with LTO, but my point is more that even with full information a compiler could still fail to perform the optimization. If the computations involved are too complicated for it, it'll just bail out and "do the safe thing".

Answer (score 12):

In pseudo-assembly language,

```
    li    #0, r0
    test  r1
    beq   L1
    li    #1, r0
L1:
```

*may or may not* be faster than

```
    test  r1
    beq   L1
    li    #1, r0
    bra   L2
L1:
    li    #0, r0
L2:
```

depending on how sophisticated the actual CPU is.  Going from simplest to fanciest:

- With *any* CPU manufactured after roughly 1990, good performance depends on the code fitting within the [instruction cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_memory).  When in doubt, therefore, minimize code size.  This weighs in favor of the first example.
- With a basic "[in-order, five-stage pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline)" CPU, which is still roughly what you get in many microcontrollers, there is a [pipeline bubble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_%28computing%29) every time a branch—conditional or unconditional—is taken, so it is also important to minimize the number of branch instructions.  This also weighs in favor of the first example.
- Somewhat more sophisticated CPUs—fancy enough to do "[out-of-order execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution)", but not fancy enough to use the best known implementations of that concept—may incur pipeline bubbles whenever they encounter [write-after-write hazards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_%28computer_architecture%29#Write_after_write_.28WAW.29).  This weighs in favor of the *second* example, where `r0` is written only once no matter what.  These CPUs are usually fancy enough to process unconditional branches in the instruction fetcher, so you *aren't* just trading the write-after-write penalty for a branch penalty.

  I don't know if anyone is still making this kind of CPU anymore.  However, the CPUs that *do* use the "best known implementations" of out-of-order execution are likely to cut corners on the less frequently used instructions, so you need to be aware that this sort of thing can happen.  A real example is [false data dependencies on the destination registers in `popcnt` and `lzcnt` on Sandy Bridge CPUs](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62011).
- At the highest end, the OOO engine will wind up issuing exactly the same sequence of internal operations for both code fragments—this is the hardware version of "don't worry about it, the compiler will generate the same machine code either way."  However, code size still does matter, and now you also should be worrying about the predictability of the conditional branch.  [Branch prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) failures potentially cause a complete pipeline *flush*, which is catastrophic for performance; see [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array) to understand how much difference this can make.

  If the branch *is* highly unpredictable, and your CPU has conditional-set or conditional-move instructions, this is the time to use them:

  ```
      li    #0, r0
      test  r1
      setne r0
  ```

  or

  ```
      li    #0, r0
      li    #1, r2
      test  r1
      movne r2, r0
  ```

  The conditional-set version is also more compact than any other alternative; if that instruction is available it is practically guaranteed to be the Right Thing for this scenario, even if the branch was predictable.  The conditional-move version requires an additional scratch register, and always wastes one `li` instruction's worth of dispatch and execute resources; if the branch was in fact predictable, the branchy version may well be faster.

Comment: I'd reword your second point as to whether the CPU has an out-of-order engine that gets delayed by write-after-write hazards.  If a CPU has an out-of-order engine that can handle such hazards without delay, there's no problem, but there's also no problem if the CPU doesn't have an out-of-order engine *at all*.

Comment: @supercat The paragraph at the end is meant to cover that case but I'll think about how to make it clearer.

Comment: I don't know what current CPUs have a cache which would cause sequentially-executed code to run faster the second time through than the first time (some flash-based ARM parts have an interface that can buffer a few rows of flash data, but can fetch code sequentially as fast as they execute it, but the key to making branch-heavy code run fast on those is to copy it to RAM).  CPUs without any out-of-order execution at all are far more common than those which would get delayed by write-after-write hazards.

Comment: This is very insightful

Answer (score 9):

In unoptimised code, the first example assigns a variable always once and sometimes twice.  The second example only ever assigns a variable once.   The conditional is the same on both code paths, so that shouldn't matter.   In optimised code, it depends on the compiler.

As always, if you are that concerned, generate the assembly and see what the compiler is actually doing.

Comment: If concerned about performance then they wont compile unoptimized.  But certainly how "good" is the optimizer depends on the compiler/version.

Comment: AFAIK there is no comment on which compiler/CPU architecture etc, so potentially, their compiler doesn't do optimising.  They could be compiling on anything from an 8-bit PIC to a 64-bit Xeon.

Answer (score 8):

What would make you think any of them even the one liner is faster or slower?

```
unsigned int fun0 ( unsigned int condition, unsigned int value )
{
    value = 5;
    if (condition) {
        value = 6;
    }
    return(value);
}
unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int condition, unsigned int value )
{

    if (condition) {
        value = 6;
    } else {
        value = 5;
    }
    return(value);
}
unsigned int fun2 ( unsigned int condition, unsigned int value )
{
    value = condition ? 6 : 5;
    return(value);
}
```

More lines of code of a high level language gives the compiler more to work with so if you want to make a general rule about it give the compiler more code to work with.  If the algorithm is the same like the cases above then one would expect the compiler with minimal optimization to figure that out.

```
00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   e3500000    cmp r0, #0
   4:   03a00005    moveq   r0, #5
   8:   13a00006    movne   r0, #6
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000010 <fun1>:
  10:   e3500000    cmp r0, #0
  14:   13a00006    movne   r0, #6
  18:   03a00005    moveq   r0, #5
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000020 <fun2>:
  20:   e3500000    cmp r0, #0
  24:   13a00006    movne   r0, #6
  28:   03a00005    moveq   r0, #5
  2c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

not a big surprise it did the first function in a different order, same execution time though.

```
0000000000000000 <fun0>:
   0:   7100001f    cmp w0, #0x0
   4:   1a9f07e0    cset    w0, ne
   8:   11001400    add w0, w0, #0x5
   c:   d65f03c0    ret

0000000000000010 <fun1>:
  10:   7100001f    cmp w0, #0x0
  14:   1a9f07e0    cset    w0, ne
  18:   11001400    add w0, w0, #0x5
  1c:   d65f03c0    ret

0000000000000020 <fun2>:
  20:   7100001f    cmp w0, #0x0
  24:   1a9f07e0    cset    w0, ne
  28:   11001400    add w0, w0, #0x5
  2c:   d65f03c0    ret
```

Hopefully you get the idea you could have just tried this if it wasnt obvious that the different implementations were not actually different.

As far as a matrix goes, not sure how that matters,

```
if(condition)
{
 big blob of code a
}
else
{
 big blob of code b
}
```

just going to put the same if-then-else wrapper around the big blobs of code be they value=5 or something more complicated.  Likewise the comparison even if it is a big blob of code it still has to be computed, and equal to or not equal to something is often compiled with the negative, if (condition) do something is often compiled as if not condition goto.

```
00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   0f 93           tst r15     
   2:   03 24           jz  $+8         ;abs 0xa
   4:   3f 40 06 00     mov #6, r15 ;#0x0006
   8:   30 41           ret         
   a:   3f 40 05 00     mov #5, r15 ;#0x0005
   e:   30 41           ret         

00000010 <fun1>:
  10:   0f 93           tst r15     
  12:   03 20           jnz $+8         ;abs 0x1a
  14:   3f 40 05 00     mov #5, r15 ;#0x0005
  18:   30 41           ret         
  1a:   3f 40 06 00     mov #6, r15 ;#0x0006
  1e:   30 41           ret         

00000020 <fun2>:
  20:   0f 93           tst r15     
  22:   03 20           jnz $+8         ;abs 0x2a
  24:   3f 40 05 00     mov #5, r15 ;#0x0005
  28:   30 41           ret         
  2a:   3f 40 06 00     mov #6, r15 ;#0x0006
  2e:   30 41
```

we just went through this exercise with someone else recently on stackoverflow.  this mips compiler interestingly in that case not only realized the functions were the same, but had one function simply jump to the other to save on code space.  Didnt do that here though

```
00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   0004102b    sltu    $2,$0,$4
   4:   03e00008    jr  $31
   8:   24420005    addiu   $2,$2,5

0000000c <fun1>:
   c:   0004102b    sltu    $2,$0,$4
  10:   03e00008    jr  $31
  14:   24420005    addiu   $2,$2,5

00000018 <fun2>:
  18:   0004102b    sltu    $2,$0,$4
  1c:   03e00008    jr  $31
  20:   24420005    addiu   $2,$2,5
```

some more targets.

```
00000000 <_fun0>:
   0:   1166            mov r5, -(sp)
   2:   1185            mov sp, r5
   4:   0bf5 0004       tst 4(r5)
   8:   0304            beq 12 <_fun0+0x12>
   a:   15c0 0006       mov $6, r0
   e:   1585            mov (sp)+, r5
  10:   0087            rts pc
  12:   15c0 0005       mov $5, r0
  16:   1585            mov (sp)+, r5
  18:   0087            rts pc

0000001a <_fun1>:
  1a:   1166            mov r5, -(sp)
  1c:   1185            mov sp, r5
  1e:   0bf5 0004       tst 4(r5)
  22:   0204            bne 2c <_fun1+0x12>
  24:   15c0 0005       mov $5, r0
  28:   1585            mov (sp)+, r5
  2a:   0087            rts pc
  2c:   15c0 0006       mov $6, r0
  30:   1585            mov (sp)+, r5
  32:   0087            rts pc

00000034 <_fun2>:
  34:   1166            mov r5, -(sp)
  36:   1185            mov sp, r5
  38:   0bf5 0004       tst 4(r5)
  3c:   0204            bne 46 <_fun2+0x12>
  3e:   15c0 0005       mov $5, r0
  42:   1585            mov (sp)+, r5
  44:   0087            rts pc
  46:   15c0 0006       mov $6, r0
  4a:   1585            mov (sp)+, r5
  4c:   0087            rts pc

00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   00a03533            snez    x10,x10
   4:   0515                    addi    x10,x10,5
   6:   8082                    ret

00000008 <fun1>:
   8:   00a03533            snez    x10,x10
   c:   0515                    addi    x10,x10,5
   e:   8082                    ret

00000010 <fun2>:
  10:   00a03533            snez    x10,x10
  14:   0515                    addi    x10,x10,5
  16:   8082                    ret
```

and compilers

with this i code one would expect the different targets to match as well

```
define i32 @fun0(i32 %condition, i32 %value) #0 {
  %1 = icmp ne i32 %condition, 0
  %. = select i1 %1, i32 6, i32 5
  ret i32 %.
}

; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind readnone
define i32 @fun1(i32 %condition, i32 %value) #0 {
  %1 = icmp eq i32 %condition, 0
  %. = select i1 %1, i32 5, i32 6
  ret i32 %.
}

; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind readnone
define i32 @fun2(i32 %condition, i32 %value) #0 {
  %1 = icmp ne i32 %condition, 0
  %2 = select i1 %1, i32 6, i32 5
  ret i32 %2
}


00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   e3a01005    mov r1, #5
   4:   e3500000    cmp r0, #0
   8:   13a01006    movne   r1, #6
   c:   e1a00001    mov r0, r1
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000014 <fun1>:
  14:   e3a01006    mov r1, #6
  18:   e3500000    cmp r0, #0
  1c:   03a01005    moveq   r1, #5
  20:   e1a00001    mov r0, r1
  24:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000028 <fun2>:
  28:   e3a01005    mov r1, #5
  2c:   e3500000    cmp r0, #0
  30:   13a01006    movne   r1, #6
  34:   e1a00001    mov r0, r1
  38:   e12fff1e    bx  lr


fun0:
    push.w  r4
    mov.w   r1, r4
    mov.w   r15, r12
    mov.w   #6, r15
    cmp.w   #0, r12
    jne .LBB0_2
    mov.w   #5, r15
.LBB0_2:
    pop.w   r4
    ret

fun1:
    push.w  r4
    mov.w   r1, r4
    mov.w   r15, r12
    mov.w   #5, r15
    cmp.w   #0, r12
    jeq .LBB1_2
    mov.w   #6, r15
.LBB1_2:
    pop.w   r4
    ret


fun2:
    push.w  r4
    mov.w   r1, r4
    mov.w   r15, r12
    mov.w   #6, r15
    cmp.w   #0, r12
    jne .LBB2_2
    mov.w   #5, r15
.LBB2_2:
    pop.w   r4
    ret
```

Now technically there is a performance difference in some of these solutions, sometimes the result is 5 case has a jump over the result is 6 code, and vice versa, is a branch faster than executing through?  one could argue but the execution should vary.  But that is more of an if condition vs if not condition in the code resulting in the compiler doing the if this jump over else execute through.  but this is not necessarily due to the coding style but the comparison and the if and the else cases in whatever syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since assembly is one of the tags, I will just assume your code is pseudo code (and not necessarily c) and translate it by human into 6502 assembly.

1st Option (without else)

```
        ldy #$00
        lda #$05
        dey
        bmi false
        lda #$06
false   brk
```

2nd Option (with else)

```
        ldy #$00
        dey
        bmi else
        lda #$06
        sec
        bcs end
else    lda #$05
end     brk
```

Assumptions: Condition is in Y register set this to 0 or 1 on the first line of either option, result will be in accumulator.

So, after counting cycles for both possibilities of each case, we see that the 1st construct is generally faster; 9 cycles when condition is 0 and 10 cycles when condition is 1, whereas option two is also 9 cycles when condition is 0, but 13 cycles when condition is 1. (*cycle counts do not include the `BRK` at the end*).

**Conclusion: `If only` is faster than `If-Else` construct.**

And for completeness, here is an optimized `value = condition + 5` solution:

```
ldy #$00
lda #$00
tya
adc #$05
brk
```

This cuts our time down to 8 cycles (*again not including the `BRK` at the end*).

Comment: Unfortunately for this answer, feeding the same source code *into a C compiler* (or into a C++ compiler) produces vastly different output than feeding it into Glen's brain. There is no difference, no "optimization" potential, between any of the alternatives at the source code level. Just use the one that's most readable (presumably the if/else one).

Comment: @Yep. The compiler is either likely to optimize *both* variants to the fastest version, or likely to add extra overhead that far outweighs the difference between the two. Or both.

Comment: Assuming that it's "*not necessarily C*" does seem a sensible choice, given that the question is tagged as C++ (unfortunately, it doesn't manage to declare the *types* of the variables involved).